# Using Elasticsearch as a replacement for database

Tags: elasticsearch

We got to a point where we have millions of queries to DB overnight with expectation that it will keep growing every day and its not sustainable for the future.

So instead of going to DB we pack the data we need to Elastic and and use that instead of direct access to DB. So instead lets say 20 queries for each object, we get one query to Elastic to get the same data.

However the problem is how do we keep it in sync with DB at all times.

We fire events in our repositories when we change something in DB, but we cant guarantee that everybody will go thru this. Sooner or later somebody will forget to update the Elastic and we end up with inconsistent data.

Not to mention that the data in Elastic are collected from 10 tables for now. So we need to fire Elastic update in 10 repos for any CRUD operation...which give you at least 30 places in code where you have to do this.

Also every night we are rebuilding the entire index (around 20 mil. documents), just to ensure we have fresh data in index before we fire our crons.

So now we are thinking to use triggers on certain tables and call some php script on each CRUD operation on those tables. Which should ensure we always have every change in Elastic and you don't have to worry about anything.

We have huge core monolith app, 50 devs working on it. Somebody uses repository methods to update data, somebody writes native query, somebody goes directly to DB to change something. Its impossible to track this, thats why we are thinking about triggers.

However this whole thing feels too complex and over-engineered and stupid. We used this approach because we already had Elastic implemented so it was relatively easy and fast to implement and it works...

So Im looking for some suggestions how can we handle this in a better way.

Since we don't have any experience with handling such a problem in our team and since our HOD said 'just use elastic, it will be fine', thats what we did. Ain't nobody got time to play around with technologies that we don't know anything about, right?

Comment: trigger approach is correct one. you can enable trigger for changes in DB and then send data to Elastic search. You can use either PHP script as you mentioned or MQ or ActiveMQ etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But the whole Elastic thing doesnt feel right, its like we are misusing that technology and then trying to fix it with triggers. I was thinking maybe there was some different approach.